# Problems when migrating to latest nx workspace

Tags: nestjs, npm-install, nomachine-nx, nx-workspace

I´m facing the same issue since I migrate my nx workspace to the latest version. The workspace contains an angular+nestjs aplications.
Everytime I try to install something that i need to install I´m facing with this. I try with --legacy-peer-deps flag and that is no good idea. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOlTV.png)

package.json dependencies:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8muoB.png)

package.json dev-dependencies:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6O1C.png)

Answer (score 0):

Solved I was having conflicts between package-lock.json